# cpp.sh open example file

Tags: c++, ide

I am using [cpp example file on cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/5clc) to test, but how can I let the cpp shell know the location of my example.txt file? It is on my own computer

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: You can use standard input.

Comment: Please edit your post with the **text** of your program.  Firewalls are preventing me from following your link.

Comment: Used `std::cin` rather than a file and paste your text into the box. Or use a `std::istringstream` and put the text of your file into the code as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't Do that. Because that is not feature of that site and that site has no access to your computer folders and files. Try to run it on installed IDE like codeblocks etc.